# Проверка на занятость файла другим процессом в php

Tags: php, goto

Выполнять перевод на другую страницу можно, если файл cls_symstore_V6.out не занят другим процессом. 
Я попыталась реализовать это таким образом:

```
start: {
$cmd = 'cls_symstore_V6.out';
if ($fh = fopen($cmd, 'r+')) {
    echo "Recording removed!" . "<br /> ";
    echo "<p><font size='3,5' color='black' face='Times New Roman'> <b> После возврата на предыдущую страницу, выполните обновление страницы. </b></font></p>";
    echo "<p><a href='http://mypage/opr/admin/store/index.php'>Вернуться назад</a></p>"; 
    fclose($fh);`введите сюда код`
} else {
    echo "Deleting... Please wait.\n";
    goto start;
}
}
```

Здесь следующая проверка: если файл удается открыть, то выводится информационное сообщение и ссылка, по которой выполняется возврат на нужную страницу. 
Если файл открыть не удается, то выводим сообщение "Deleting... Please wait." и по `goto` возвращаемся в `start` и вновь повторяется проверка, пока условие не будет верно и я не получу ссылку, чтобы покинуть страницу. 
Мой способ, к сожалению, не увенчался успехом. 

**Мой рабочий вариант через do-while:**

```
$i = 0;
do {
    if ($fh = fopen("cls_symstore_V6.out", "r+")) {
        echo "Recording removed!" . "<br /> ";
        echo "<p><font size='3,5' color='black' face='Times New Roman'> <b> После возврата на предыдущую страницу, выполните обновление страницы. </b></font></p>";
        echo "<p><a href='http://mypage/opr/admin/store/index.php'>Вернуться назад</a></p>"; 
        fclose($fh);
        $i = $i + 1;
        break;
    } else {
        echo "Выполняется удаление. Пожалуйста, подождите...\n";
        $string_time_out="\\\\".$server_name."\\".$path_dir_2."\\".$my_log.".out";
    //    echo $string_time_out;
        $my->time_out_client($string_time_out,32);
        echo "Recording removed!" . "<br /> ";
        echo "<p><font size='3,5' color='black' face='Times New Roman'> <b> После возврата на предыдущую страницу, выполните обновление страницы. </b></font></p>";
        echo "<p><a href='http://mypage/opr/admin/store/index.php'>Вернуться назад</a></p>";
        $i = $i + 1;
        break;
    }    
} while ($i = 1);
```

**Всем спасибо, вопрос закрыт.**

Comment: 1. `goto` замечательно заменит `do {} while();` 2. зачем вы заморачиваетесь с файловыми блокировками? База данных не будет подходящим решением?

Comment: Как вариант, можно создавать временный файлик в начале процесса удаления, а после его окончания удалять. И проверку делать на существование именно этого файла: `file_exists()`. Проблема будет только одна: если процесс удаления упадет с ошибкой, временный файл будет жить вечно.

Comment: @tutankhamun 1. Но ведь выполнится выражение даже если оно будет неверно, если я воспользуюсь do-while. Разве нет? <br> 2. К сожалению, не обладаю достаточными знаниями, чтобы воспользоваться БД. Я даже представить не могу, как это условие вообще связано с БД.

Comment: @АлександрГрибенников спасибо за совет, но лучше так рисковать не буду. Удаление происходит на другом сервере, а там уже может произойти что угодно. Я, конечно, пойму и удалю вручную файл, но кто-нибудь может об этом не знать.

Comment: @tutankhamun мне тогда `break` надо будет использовать, верно? Хм... только сообщения же уже будут выведены...

Comment: @tutankhamun вот таким образом попробовала (отредактировала вопрос), но осталась проблемка. =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Мой рабочий вариант:**

```
$i = 0;
do {
    if ($fh = fopen("cls_symstore_V6.out", "r+")) {
        echo "Recording removed!" . "<br /> ";
        echo "<p><font size='3,5' color='black' face='Times New Roman'> <b> После возврата на предыдущую страницу, выполните обновление страницы. </b></font></p>";
        echo "<p><a href='http://mypage/opr/admin/store/index.php'>Вернуться назад</a></p>"; 
        fclose($fh);
        $i = $i + 1;
        break;
    } else {
        echo "Выполняется удаление. Пожалуйста, подождите...\n";
        $string_time_out="\\\\".$server_name."\\".$path_dir_2."\\".$my_log.".out";
    //    echo $string_time_out;
        $my->time_out_client($string_time_out,32);
        echo "Recording removed!" . "<br /> ";
        echo "<p><font size='3,5' color='black' face='Times New Roman'> <b> После возврата на предыдущую страницу, выполните обновление страницы. </b></font></p>";
        echo "<p><a href='http://mypage/opr/admin/store/index.php'>Вернуться назад</a></p>";
        $i = $i + 1;
        break;
    }    
} while ($i = 1);
```

**Всем спасибо за советы.**